# Get the image name when Dropzone.js finishes to do the process

Tags: jquery, laravel, dropzone.js, dropzone

js with Laravel to upload the images of the website, what I want to do it's to get the name of that file that I already uploaded what I mean is this:

I have my Dropzone.js code:

```
Dropzone.options.myAwesomeDropzone = {
        paramName: "file", // Las imágenes se van a usar bajo este nombre de parámetro
        autoProcessQueue:true,
        required:true,
        acceptedFiles: ".png,.jpg,.gif,.bmp,.jpeg",
        addRemoveLinks: true,
        maxFiles:8,
        parallelUploads : 100,
        maxFilesize:5,
        init: function() {
            this.on("success", function(file, response) {
                $('.dz-preview').remove();
            })
        }
    };
```

This is my HTML:

```
<div  id="home_6" class="tab-pane fade active in" role="tabpanel">
                                            <br>
                                            <form action="{{ asset('/image/store') }}" method="post" class="dropzone" id="my-awesome-dropzone">
                                                {{ csrf_field() }}
                                            </form>
                                            <br>
                                            <div class="row text-center" id="files">
                                                <div class="col-md-3">  
                                                    <img src="{{ url('admin/dist/img/thumb-1.jpg') }}" />
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col-md-3">  
                                                    <img src="{{ url('admin/dist/img/thumb-1.jpg') }}" />
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col-md-3">  
                                                    <img src="{{ url('admin/dist/img/thumb-1.jpg') }}" />
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col-md-3">  
                                                    <img src="{{ url('admin/dist/img/thumb-1.jpg') }}" />
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
```

And this is my Laravel upload code

```
public function store(Request $request)
{

$file = $request->file('file');
$path = public_path() . '/files';
$fileName = uniqid() . $file->getClientOriginalName();

$file->move($path, $fileName);

}
```

How you can see this Dropzone works to upload the image automaticly and it's ok with that, then it goes to the controller in the function store it's when is stored, how you can check I have a function wwhen it finished to upload:

```
this.on("success", function(file, response) {
                $('.dz-preview').remove();
            })
```

In that function i'd like to recover the name which was used to store the image in the files folder, I mean if I put alert in there it says hiworld.png for example.

How can I get the file name? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the 'success' callback you can get the name of the file by calling:

```
file.name
```

Just console.log the file variable and you will see all properties.

Also, since you already call the filename in the controller:

```
$file->getClientOriginalName();
```

you can also return it from the controller. Then in the 'success' callback, get it from the response. It depends on what you want to achieve.